# required field notification using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

Hi, image above is occured when I try to submit button with textbox properties

```
required = true
```

can anyone tell me how to show it even before I clicked the button?

Comment: do you mean to show it on losing focus?

Comment: show the message "please fill...."

Answer (score 1):

you can use [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) and [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) events with jquery for losing focus from your textbox.

you can use jquery function like this..

```
   $("#idOfTextField").blur(function(){

  //your code

});
```

see this if it helps..

Comment: lose means as soon as lost focus from your textbox this event fires. you can show the alert message for filling value after lose focus from your textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use focus() instead when user focus on field.

```
$("#id").focus(function(){
    alert('Please fill out this field');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*I know this does not do exactly as you require but might be another option.*

A simple way may be to give the user a more subtle indication that the field is required, e.g. change the border to red with css:

```
input:required {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/adrianwhite/pen/qVLoOy

FYI: required does not need ="true" see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required